# Create dynamic slider in Umbraco using asp net razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, umbraco

I managed to create a simple slider using slick slider  but it just displays a list of images, not a slider,  here is what I have done:

1. I linked all slick sliders files in my master

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"/>
```

2. added javascript for calling the slider at the end of my page.

   $(document).ready(function(){
                       $('.slides').slick({
                           autoplay:true,
                           pauseOnHover:true
                       });
                    });
3. I created a macro from partial view macros files by selected a snippet called  gallery and edited it a little bit, here is how it looks:

   @inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
   @*  Macro to display a gallery of images from media the media section.
       Works with either a 'Single Media Picker' or a 'Multiple Media Picker' macro parameters (see below).

   ```
   How it works:
       - Confirm the macro parameter has been passed in with a value
       - Loop through all the media Id's passed in (might be a single item, might be many)
       - Display any individual images, as well as any folders of images

   Macro Parameters To Create, for this macro to work:
   Alias:mediaIds     Name:Select folders and/or images    Type: Multiple Media Picker
                                                           Type: (note: you can use a Single Media Picker if that's more appropriate to your needs)
   ```

   *@

   ```
   @{ var mediaIds = Model.MacroParameters["mediaIds"]; }
   @if (mediaIds != null)
   {
       <div class="slides">
           @foreach (var mediaId in mediaIds.ToString().Split(','))
           {
               var media = Umbraco.Media(mediaId);

               @* a single image *@
               if (media.DocumentTypeAlias == "Image")
               {
                   @Render(media);
               }

               @* a folder with images under it *@
               if (media.Children("Image").Any())
               {
                   foreach (var image in media.Children("Image"))
                   {
                       @Render(image);
                   }
               }

           }
       </div>
   }

   @helper Render(dynamic item)
   {
       <div>
       <img src="@item.umbracoFile" alt="@item.Name" />
       </div>
   }
   ```
4. In macro, I added those parameters  Alias: mediaIds Name: Select files and /or Images, type: Multi-Media Picker
5. I rendered my partial view macro on my home page as follows:

   @Umbraco.RenderMacro("Gallery", new {mediaIds="1120,1118,1119"})

Now when I preview my homepage i get a list of Images instead of a slider as I want, can anyone help to figure out why it returns a list of images instead of a slider? am a newbie to asp net and Umbraco,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the Url of your item, not access to the file itself:

```
 <img src="@item.Url" alt="@item.Name" />
```

I really recommend you to use strongly typed models instead dynamics, they really make your life much easier

Comment: thank you, may  be u know if its possible to use slider revolution in umbraco ?  if yes can you provide some tutorials on how implement it in umbraco

Comment: Sure it's possible, Umbraco doesn't change anything you can do on the frontend. Just follow the instructions of the plugin. Try to install it with static content and then just replace it with content coming form the backoffice. You can try this plugin to make the content editing easier: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/uskyslider/